# How to make a DOM handler enumerable in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, webkit, ecmascript-5, dontenum

I need to enumerate all the properties of my DOM elements which I previously modified. I could do it with Firefox, Chrome and Opera but I could not with Safari (I don't care about IE for the moment).

```
<a id="link">Link...</a>
<script>
    var link = document.getElementById("link");
    var foo = function (baz) {};
    link.onclick = foo;
    alert ("onclick" in link); // true
    alert (link.hasOwnProperty("onclick")); // true
    alert (link.propertyIsEnumerable("onclick")); 
    // false with Chrome, Safari, Opera*
</script>
```

*: Although the property is not enumerable in Opera it is anyway enumerated!!!

```
for (p in link) 
    if (p==="onclick") 
        alert (p); // onclick
```

I can make the third `alert` output `true` in Chrome by deleting the `onclick` property  before assigning it:

```
delete link.onclick;
```

But the property is not yet enumerated in Safari.

I even tried with the EcmaScript 5 Object method [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
Object.defineProperty (link, onclick, {
    value: foo,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true
});
```

but it returns the error:

> TypeError: defineProperty is not supported on DOM Objects

Any suggestions?

P.S. Why does Safari behave different from Chrome although they are both based on Webkit?

Comment: In answer to your PS: Webkit is the rendering engine. For Javascript, Safari uses the JavaScriptCore engine (Squirrelfish), Chrome uses V8.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the [useragent](http://www.useragentstring.com/) to the Webkit version in which the  EcmaScript5 Object methods were implemented in [Webkit JavaScriptCore](https://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/01/15/ecmascript-5-and-webkitjavascriptcore/). The Webkit version of Chrome is different from that of Safari, so standards support will vary accordingly.